# Unable to pass std::function into boost::asio async_accept handler

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, boost-asio

I am trying to write a server which takes a custom handler from the user using boost asio. I am able to call statements from inside the async_accept handler but whenever I call the handler received by the server, It results in a segfault.

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class Server {
private:
  asio::io_service &io_service;
  tcp::acceptor acc;
  tcp::endpoint endpoint;

public:
  Server(asio::io_service &io) : io_service{io}, acc{io} {}

  void listen(unsigned short port);
  void accept(function<void()> handler);
};

void Server::listen(unsigned short port) {
  endpoint.port(port);

  acc.open(endpoint.protocol());
  acc.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));

  acc.bind(endpoint);
  acc.listen();
}

void Server::accept(function<void()> handler) {
  tcp::socket socket(io_service);


  acc.async_accept(socket, [this, h = handler](const system::error_code &error) {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    h();

    accept(h);
  });
}

int main() {
  asio::io_service io_service;
  Server s(io_service);

  s.listen(8000);

  s.accept([]() { cout << "Connection Accepted" << endl; });

  io_service.run();
}
```

However when I use `std::bind` to the lambda I pass it magically runs. I am unable to understand why and would also like to know if this approach is performant ?

```cpp
void Server::accept(function<void()> handler) {
  tcp::socket socket(io_service);

  auto h = std::bind(handler);

  acc.async_accept(socket, [this, h](const system::error_code &error) {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    h();

    accept(h);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not with a handler.

Undefined behaviour is caused by accessing dangling reference to `socket` as local variable.

You call `async_accept` which takes the socket by reference as first parameter: According to [official reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/async_accept/overload1.html), the caller (you) is responsible to prolong its lifetime until handler is called:

> The socket into which the new connection will be accepted. Ownership
>   of the peer object is retained by the caller, which must guarantee
>   that it is valid until the handler is called.

You should wrap socket in some kind of smart pointer and then pass this pointer to lambda to prolong its lifetime:

```
  std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(io_service);


  acc.async_accept(*socket, [this, h = handler, socket](const system::error_code &error) {
```

---

I hope, you are aware that `async_XXX` returns immediately, hence *socket* is deleted as well when the function returns.

Comment: I would not use `std::function`, it has some overhead. Instead, make accept as template function, taking any callable object `template<class F> void accept(F)` and inside that function move your handler to lambda `[h = std::move(handler)]`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice... I am just a high school student, so you will ignore my stupidity.

Comment: But I want the definition of the handler to be specified

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achive. Handler's type is specified by its definition, what you do when writing `[]() { cout << "Connection Accepted" << endl; }`.